# Avahi-Daemon can't discover RaspberryPi

Tags: dns, raspberrypi, avahi

Ubuntu 22.04 is unable to find raspberrypi.local on my network.

However, my iPhone can find it.

PI is running over ethernet.

I've restarted the avahi-daemon.service on the pi, and also avahi-daemon on my local PC.

```
➜  ~ avahi-resolve-host-name raspberrypi.local
Failed to resolve host name 'raspberrypi.local': Timeout reached
```

I'm able to browse to it via IP Address, and I have fixed temporarily using HOSTS file.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it by restarting my switch (not my router).

This makes no sense....

Comment: The OS on a switch can freeze, so it also might have to be rebooted once in a while.